# EXC_ARITHMETIC in UIFlowLayoutSection.updateEstimatedSizeForSection

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I get the following error in simulator when trying to display a UICollectionView:

```
    UIKit`-[_UIFlowLayoutSection updateEstimatedSizeForSection:]:
    ...
    0x106d32858 <+582>:  movq   0x416909(%rip), %rcx      ; _UIFlowLayoutSection._validItemRange
    0x106d3285f <+589>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
->  0x106d32861 <+591>:  divq   0x8(%rcx,%rbx) 

Thread 1: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0)
```

I have set the estimated cell size correctly and also set the collection view height bigger than the cell height. All insets have been set to 0. But before the crash I still get the following warnings:

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
Please check the values return by the delegate.
The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fe65d28b7c0>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fe65c859000; frame = (5 63; 365 110); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe65d28bea0>; animations = { opacity=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fe65d702fd0>; bounds.origin=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fe65d704610>; bounds.size=<CABasicAnimation: 0x7fe65d704630>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe65d03a0b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1798, 110}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fe65d28b7c0>.
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you down vote, please explain. This clearly is a bug in UICollectionView. I managed to find a way around it, but that does not mean that UICollectionView working properly.

Comment: Happened to me as well. used collectionview with estimatedItemSize inside stackview , when changing the collectionview from hide to unhide and reload data the same crash. my solution - remove the estimatedItemSize and calculate the itemcell size for each cell.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? Running into the same issue, but only on iOS 10 (and below). Seems like a bug, but I'd prefer not to calculate the item size for each cell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by setting the UIImageView size to fixed in the collection view cell instead of having constraints to stretch the image view to the size of the cell.

This is weird because UICollectionView should not scale the cell to larger than the size returned in the dataSource. Also, what has the UIImageView size got to do with the cell size when it has clipsToBounds = true? UICollectionView shouldn't even know what views the cell contains as long as the cell itself has the correct size.